# Форма доконаного виду дієслова "відати" і її відмінювання

Tags: дієслова, дієвідмінювання

Згідно з дієсловами **відповідати - відповісти**; **розповідати - розповісти**, форма доконаного виду дієслова *відати* має бути вісти.

В *Словарю української мови* Б. Грінченка дано архаїчний спосіб відмінювання:

**Я - вім

Ти - віси

Він - вість**

Але питання в тому, що жоден словник, опріче *Словаря української мови*, не знає такого відмінювання.

Чи зустрічається зараз така форма? І чи є інші згадки про таку форму, опріч *Словаря української мови*?

Answer (score 3):

Доконана форма утворюється префіксальним способом: *звідати, довітати, провідати.*

[ЗВІДУВАТИ](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) ую, уєш, недок., ЗВІДАТИ, аю, аєш, док., що.
розм. Довідуватися про щось, осягати розумом що-небудь. Приклади

> – Служать і радять [духи] жриці чужій, пророкині [пророчиці]. Від них звідує все. Тому і нема для неї таїни. (Н. Королева)
> Багато звідав [Ганц] істин, зазирнувши світові в обличчя, але не став щасливішим у глибині своєї бентежної душі. (О. Полторацький)

Бачити, зустрічати що-небудь. Приклади

> Любив [Олекса], ой, як любив ходити невідомими місцями, звідувати ніколи ще не звідані гори. (Г. Хоткевич)
> Де тільки не ходила вона, яких лісів, яких земель не звідала, а знайти не знайшла [сина]. (Д. Міщенко)

Переживати, переносити на собі, зазнавати чого-небудь. Приклади

> – Скільки-то ви горя на своїм віку звідали!... (Панас Мирний)
> Не натішиться на неї ненька, Береже і пестить молоду. А вона – берізонька тоненька – Вже розлуки звідала біду. (Л. Дмитерко)
> Я звідав радість у труді, І щастя творчості, і піт. (М. Нагнибіда)

Відчувати що-небудь. Приклади

> Її така важка туга пройняла, такий жаль увійшов у саме серце, якого вона досі ніколи не звідувала. (Панас Мирний)
> Хотілося звідати того солодкого, як мед, почуття, що у піснях зветься коханням.... (В. Малик)

[ПРОВІДАТИ](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)
перев. док. Узнати, дізнатися про що-небудь (перев. таємне, приховуване). Приклади

> [Сидір:] Та чи ви знаєте, що Параска провідала якось, що ви сватаєтесь, там репетує, – мало не вискочила на хату! (І. Карпенко-Карий)
> В тім селі .. провідав [паламар], яку се дяк хоче ману пустить. (з казки)
> Я, щоб ви знали, провідав того світа – був, як то кажуть, у бувальцях. (Марко Вовчок)

Comment: Так, доконана форма дієслова твориться саме префіксальним способом. Залежно від префіксу, змінюватиметься лексична форма слова та емоційна окраска. "Звідати" - осягнути думкою, зрозуміти, пізнати. "Провідати, вивідати" - дізнатися про приховане, утаємничене. Дякую за ваші зусилля.

Answer (score 3):

*Вім*, *віси*, *вість* — це ще праслов'янські форми теперішнього часу дієслова *відати* ([*věmь, *věsi, *věstь](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/v%C4%9Bd%C4%9Bti#Conjugation)), що збереглися зокрема в церковнослов'янській ([вѣмь, вѣси, вѣстъ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%A3%D0%B4%D1%A3%D1%82%D0%B8#Conjugation)). В українській використовуються здебільшого в [конфесійному стилі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F). Наголошую: це *не* майбутній доконаний, а *теперішній недоконаний* (фактично повні синоніми до *відаю*, *відаєш*, *відає*, але тепер мають специфічне стильове забарвлення).

> [[Ригорович](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80_%D0%9F%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BA_(%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6)#%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F_%D0%9F%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B0):] Сiя двер, з ню же проiзведенiє сотворяєть увесь род чоловiчеський, бисть погибшая; i се паки обрiтеся, но како? не **вiм**! (Григорій Квітка-Основ'яненко, [«Конотопська відьма»](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0), 1833).
>
> Не **вім**, за що їм так довіря князь, нароблять вони колись нам досточортів лиха!.. (Олекса Стороженко, «Марко Проклятий», 1863).
>
> Ти один, господи, **віси**! (Іван Франко, листи).
>
> …Поет оспівує… тих, імення їх же ти, Господи, **віси**, що головами наклали в безощадній, часто сліпій боротьбі… (Сергій Єфремов, «Історія українського письменства», 1924).
>
> Як стрінемо першого попа, то золотого дам на панахиду за душу «раба божія, єго же ім'я ти Господи **віси**…» (Андрій Чайковський, «Сагайдачний», 1929).
>
> [Бог **вість**](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3+%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&dicts=1&highlight=on) (Агатангел Кримський та Сергій Єфремов, «Російсько-український словник», 1924–1933).

Посилання на результати пошуку в [корпусі ГРАК](https://uacorpus.org):

- [вім](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac17&queryselector=word&keyword=%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BC&refs==doc.date,=doc.author,=doc.title&sort=%5B%7B%22skey%22:%22kw%22,%22attr%22:%22doc.date%22,%22ctx%22:%220%22,%22bward%22:%22%22,%22icase%22:%22%22%7D%5D&showresults=1);
- [віси](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac17&queryselector=word&keyword=%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BC&refs==doc.date,=doc.author,=doc.title&sort=%5B%7B%22skey%22:%22kw%22,%22attr%22:%22doc.date%22,%22ctx%22:%220%22,%22bward%22:%22%22,%22icase%22:%22%22%7D%5D&showresults=1).

Answer (score 2):

**[ВІДАТИ](https://sum.in.ua/s/vidaty)** - знати, мати про що-небудь уявлення, відомості.

Відповідне дієслово доконаного виду — **[пові́дати](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)**. Це слово є архаїзмом і в сучасній українській мові зустрічається зрідка. Зазвичай його замінюють синонімами **повідомити**, **розказати**, **розповісти**.

```
Я    - повідав  / повідаю 
Ти   - повідав  / повідаєш 
Він  - повідав  / повідає
Вона - повідала / повідає
```